# Word Add-in is Working on developing pc but not on others

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-addins

I have created a word add-in which is working on my developing pc but when I try it at others it fails.

The add-in contains a word add-in part and then a windowsForm Application.
The word add-in part is saving the current word document as a htm document and then the windows form part works with that document.
When I install the add-in on other pc it works until that point. I can click the button and it saves the file, but after that it just gets a gray screen and stops without opening the windows form. On my PC it then opens the windows Form and I can work with the Program.

```
namespace WordHilfeUpdaterAddin
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            ReaderWriter readwriter = new ReaderWriter();
            // deletes the folder if exists
            readwriter.Ordnerloschen(@"C:\temphilfeupdate");
            // creates temp folder
            readwriter.erstelleoernder(@"C:\temphilfeupdate");
            //saves the doc as filtered html document
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(@"C:\temphilfeupdate\Wordhtm",WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML);
            // security save
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Save();
            // nessecary to get word of the file
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Close();
            //starts the program
            MainClass main = new MainClass();
            main.start();
            //deletes the temp folder
            readwriter.Ordnerloschen(@"C:\temphilfeupdate");            
        }
    }
}

namespace HilfeUpdater
{
    class MainClass
    {
        [STAThread]        
        //starts the windows form
        public void start()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new HilfeUpdater());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well... what's different between the computers? (Same version of windows? Same version of Word?) Can you describe how its not working?

Comment: The Problem was that i connected to an local sql server... So when i tryed to connect to the sql server on an other pc it crashed...